# Has $\max\{cx:Ax\le b\}$ an optimal solution $x_1=\sqrt 2$ with $A\in \{-1,0,1\}^{m*n}$ with exactly one $1$ and one $-1$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let be

- $A\in \{-1,0,1\}^{m*n}$ with exactly one $1$ and one $-1$ and zeroes
  at each line.
- $c\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{j=n}c_j=0$.
- $b\in\mathbb{Z}^m$ positive.

How to start to show that the linear program $\max\{c^Tx:Ax\le b\}$ has an optimal solution $x_1=\sqrt 2$?

Comment: If you can find a solution $\vec x$ with $x_1<\sqrt2$ and another solution $\vec y$ with $y_1>\sqrt2$, you can use convexity of the feasible region to deduce the result. (Just take $\vec z = t \vec x + (1-t)\vec y$ for suitable $t\in [0,1]$.)

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman Thank you for your interest! Yet, how may I find such solutions as far as I don't know $b$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood you correctly, but the solution to an LP with rational data $(A,b,c)$ is always rational.

Comment: No; there EXISTS a solution which is rational. You can have other solutions as well. ... For instance, maximize $x$ such that $x\le 1$ and $y\le 2$, with the nonnegativity conditions $x,y\ge 0$. $(1,\sqrt2)$ is an optimum solution.

Comment: absolutely true